# How to change a button's color when clicked on it and change it back to its original color when the button is clicked again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-boot

In this case, my Upvote button is transparent, and when I click on it, its background color changes from transparent to green. I need to make this button transparent when I click on it again. I tried the following codes

```js
function vote(){
  var upVoteBtn = document.getElementById("upVote");
  upVoteBtn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  upVoteBtn.style.color = "black";
}
```

```html
<button id="upVote" onclick=vote()>upVote</button>
```

Comment: Instead of setting inline styles, what you should be doing, is simply _toggle_ a class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle

Comment: And look into Event Listeners instead of using inline JS for your click: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @IUKottahchchi ... From all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 2):

As @CBroe mentioned, instead of adding style in js, consider making a class with styles you need, `toggle` this class with a `listener` on button click.

```js
document.getElementById("upVote").addEventListener("click", () => {
  event.target.classList.toggle("upvoted")
})
```

```css
.upvoted{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<button id="upVote">upVote</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
var btnToggle = true;
var upVoteBtn = document.getElementById("upVote");

function vote(){
    if (btnToggle){
        upVoteBtn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        btnToggle = false;
    } else{
        upVoteBtn.style.backgroundColor = null;
        btnToggle = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="upVote" onclick=vote()>upVote</button>
```

If you want to make it transparent, then simply use `upVoteBtn.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";` instead of `null`. Just like below.

```js
var btnToggle = true;
var upVoteBtn = document.getElementById("upVote");
upVoteBtn.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";

function vote(){
    if (btnToggle){
        upVoteBtn.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        btnToggle = false;
    } else{
        upVoteBtn.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        btnToggle = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="upVote" onclick=vote()>upVote</button>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function vote(element){
        element.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.btn.active{
  background:green;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn{
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="upVote" onclick=vote(this)>upVote</button>
```

---

`Solution of Problem`

- `vote(this)` send element of button
- `toggle()` use to add and remove active class
- `.btn.active` check button have active class or not

Answer (score 0):

The OP should make use of the [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)'s [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method. In addition the OP should feel encouraged to drop inline event handling in favor of using the [selector API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) together with [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```js
function toggleVotingState({ currentTarget }) {
  currentTarget.classList.toggle('voted');
}
document
  .querySelector('#upVote')
  .addEventListener('click', toggleVotingState);
```

```css
.voted {
  color: black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="upVote">upVote</button>
```